# Same Java code returns different result running from Netbeans and -JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans, encoding, jar

When i try to run java code using Netbeans, everything is good and RC2 encryption code gives 
`5B\q\OI5c¸ä3î1Ü`. But running compiled jar file from windows the output is different `5B?\q\O?I5cä3???1Ü?`. Problems solves if i run the same jar file from linux.

Comment: Nowhere near enough information to tell accurately, but it's very likely that the terminal you're running under doesn't have the correct fonts and/or locale settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly just the way the console handles non-ASCII characters in each case. However, that's a corollary to you doing something you shouldn't to start with: converting an arbitrary `byte[]` to `String` when you shouldn't do so, or at least in a way that you shouldn't, e.g with `new String(byte[])`. Even specifying a `Charset` (which you should always do when converting between text and a binary representation of that text, in either direction) wouldn't help here.

The result of encryption is *not* encoded text - it's just bytes. Ideally you should keep that as a `byte[]` - it's just binary data, after all. If you *do* need to convert it into text though, you should use hex or base64 to do so, as that way you'll get an ASCII representation which is *always* reversible to get back to your original binary data.

For base64, there's a [good public domain library](http://iharder.net/base64) you might want to consider using.